# How to return an instance of a class depending on its type?

Tags: dart

```
abstract class Base {}

class A extends Base {
  void methodA() {}
}

class B extends Base {
  void methodB() {}
}

// returning `dynamic` from here works but it doesn't allow auto-correction
Base getClass(Base base) {
  if (base is A)
    return A();
  else
    return B();
}

void main() {
  getClass(A()).methodA(); // how to make this
  getClass(B()).methodB(); // and this work?
}
```

I want `getClass` to return `A` or `B` depending on the type passed to it so I can directly use `methodA`/`methodB` directly on it.

I know I can also use `as` like:

```
(getClass(A()) as A).methodA(); // works
```

But I think there exist some better solution because I am using this in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to call methodA if the object is of type A. The best way to do this is probably using type tests:

```dart
var myVar = A();
if (myVar is A) {
  myVar.methodA();
}
```

Alternatively you could put methods in the parent object that would dispatch the method if available:

```
abstract class Base {
  void methodAIfAvailable() {
    if (this is A) {
      (this as A).methodA();
    }
  }

  void methodBIfAvailable() {
    if (this is B) {
      (this as B).methodB();
    }
  }
}

class A extends Base {
  void methodA() {}
}

class B extends Base {
  void methodB() {}
}
```

If it is always the case that when you have an object of type `Base`, you need to execute `methodA()` if the object is of type `A` and `methodB()` if the object is of type `B`, then consider using method overloading:

```
abstract class Base {
  void method();
}

class A extends Base {
  @overload
  void method() { /* do what methodA does */ }
}

class B extends Base {
  @overload
  void method() { /* do what methodB does */ }
}

void main() {
  Base obj = // gets a Base object
  obj.method(); // calls the correct implementation depending on whether the object is A or B
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Without casting (as A) it is impossible to know the exact return type of Base Class.

If casting return value is not suitable for you, then you can try declaring methods in abstract class as:

```
abstract class Base {
  void methodA(){}
  void methodB(){}
}
```

By this way you don't need to cast return value before call method on that value.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution isn't quite good, because I'll have to override `methodA` in class `B` and similarly the other one for no reason.

Comment: You don't need to override all methods to both class. Just place all methods from Class A & B with empty function body to class Base. Then  you are good to go. You don't need to override methodA in class B.

Comment: Yes, I understand but it isn't a good approach, it's better I stick with `as`, because I have around 10-12 methods, the app architecture would just ruin itself.